# CryptoJS AES. How to repeat encryption

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptojs

I have a problem with AES encryption.
I have any encrypted text.

```
var keyString = 'b46393431e8dfaa3feec333b6ba02d0b277b8552f092e49e3a2e9b9739ac23ea';
var message1 = "message to encrypt";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message1, keyString, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB});
console.log(encrypted); //U2FsdGVkX1862TrLeAHJssPnGWVfQ9AzPtF64560nerd1xOM+72ad+ZdyXMl5sLF
```

And now, I want to check, that at next time I'll encrypted the same text. I don't have variable message, but I have encrypted text.

```
var message2 = "message to encrypt";
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encrypted.iv.toString());
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyString);
var encrypted1 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message2, key, {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB});
console.log(encrypted1); //xbPp9LFwl12hkLKwlvjpMaVj5Rss7YUbR0fP61wFXw8=
```

But if variable message1 == message2, I want to get the same encrypted text.
If I'll set iv and key as in second time - I'll get the next time the same result. But as first time I want to generate IV in encription function random. Is it possible?

Comment: Your understanding of what an `Intitialization Vector (IV)` is is flawed.

Comment: Ok, may be you will help me to understand it? I'm trying to solve this problem for several days.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, CryptoJS treats keys and passwords differently. If you provide a string it will automatically derive a key and IV from the password and a salt. So you will need to provide an identical salt if your `keyString` is indeed a string, or an identical IV if it is a key.

You could prefix the IV (generated before calling `encrypt`) to the ciphertext if you want to retrieve it later on. If I'm not mistaken the salt is already put into the ciphertext for passwords (OpenSSL) compatible, so you can retrieve it from byte 8..15 after decoding.

Note that re-use of the IV or salt is normally not safe for any mode of operation (CFB in your example), although it depends on the mode of operation *how* unsafe a repeat of the IV is. It's fine for making a compare but I would not store multiple ciphertexts with identical IV or salt.

Usually there are better ways of creating the same functionality for peculiar schemes as you've described above.

Comment: What way you prefer for this problem? If I understand correctly, the key is an object, and password - string, yes? If I have an object key - I can set IV. But if I have string - at encryption it will be generated randomly. I don' understand you suggestion prefix IV o the ciphertext. Can you write sample on JS?

Comment: no. I can't understand, if I'll use PBKDF, what salt should I use?

Comment: `var keyString = 'b46393431e8dfaa3feec333b6ba02d0b277b8552f092e49e3a2e9b9739ac23ea';
var message = "message to encrypt";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, keyString);
var iv = encrypted.iv;
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(keyString, encrypted.salt);
var encrypted1 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {iv: iv});`

What's wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that these libs are very different (cryptoJS && mcrypt)

Comment: but I need implementation on JavaScript - not on PHP (client side)

Comment: My bad, I simply wrote mcrypt instead of CryptJS. If you already have a key, then use the 3 argument version of encrypt and if you want the same ciphertext use a static IV. Butnote that ztatic IV s are not safe. You would want to hex decode your key first though.

Comment: Is it means that I can't at first time use password for encrypt, and get IV from encrypted. And at the next time - use this IV to get the same encrypted text? I have problems with using IV second time. Or I don't know how to make key from password.